# How to determine when an application becomes active and in-active?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

How can you determine when a particular application becomes active and in-active?

Example, the user opens chrome, then switches to textmate, then switches back to chrome.

I want to be able to track when and what the active application is.

Comment: your requirement for ALL apps isn't clear IMHO

Comment: @Daij-Djan sorry for not being clear, but I wrote "how can you determine when a particular application...", and I gave an example if a user opens chrome, then textmate etc.  Not sure what else I could have said?

Comment: I gave an appropriate answer anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current active application:

```
NSRunningApplication * frontmost;
frontmost = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] runningApplications] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"active == YES"]][0];
```

You can get a notification every time a new application is activated like so:

```
_myObserver = [[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] notificationCenter] addObserverForName:NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification
                                                                object:nil
                                                                 queue:nil
                                                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
    NSLog(@"New application: %@", [[note userInfo] objectForKey:NSWorkspaceApplicationKey]);
}];
```

Answer (score 6):

In the NSApplicationDelegate you have

Managing Active Status -- for your OWN app only!

- applicationWillBecomeActive:
- applicationDidBecomeActive:
- applicationWillResignActive:
- applicationDidResignActive:

#### those are in fact NSNotifications sent by the your own NSApplication object

---

one notification is for ALL apps!

- NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification

#### that's sent by the NSWorkspace Object

Comment: I'm referring to ALL applications currently running, not my own app.  These are specific to my own app no?

Comment: … because the `applicationWill/Did…` notifications are sent by the NSApplication object (representing your own application), whereas `NSWorkspaceDidActivate/DeactivateApplicationNotification` are sent by the NSWorkspace object (about any application).

Comment: yip, thanks for the clarification :) I edited my answer with that